# A simple makefile with chain dependencies. "linker input file unused because linking not done" and g++ -c

Tags: c++, compilation, makefile, g++

I just started using makefiles and came across a problem. (C++ project)
I'm trying to make a dependency chain:

main.cpp depends on class a. And class a depends on class b.

The main idea is to recompile class a using the allready compiled class b, while class a doesn't have the main() function. (When class a is modified)

### Here is my makefile:

makefile

```
all: main.o

main.o: main.cpp classa.o
        g++ main.cpp classa.o -o main.o

classa.o: classa.h classa.cpp classb.o
        g++ -c classa.cpp classb.o -o classa.o

classb.o: classb.h classb.cpp
        g++ -c classb.cpp -o classb.o
```

### And the code:

main.cpp

```
#include "classa.h"

int main() {
    ClassA a;
    return 0;
}
```

classa.h

```
#ifndef CLASSA_H
#define CLASSA_H

#include "classb.h"

class ClassA {
private:
    ClassB b;
public:
    ClassA();
};

#endif // CLASSA_H
```

classa.cpp

```
#include "classa.h"

ClassA::ClassA() {
}
```

classb.h

```
#ifndef CLASSB_H
#define CLASSB_H

class ClassB {
public:
    ClassB();
};

#endif // CLASSB_H
```

classb.cpp

```
#include "classb.h"

ClassB::ClassB() {
}
```

### The Problem:

When i use *make -f makefile* i get the following error:

```
g++ -c classb.cpp -o classb.o
g++ -c classa.cpp classb.o -o classa.o
g++: warning: classb.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
g++ main.cpp classa.o -o main.o
classa.o: In function `ClassA::ClassA()':
classa.cpp:(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `ClassB::ClassB()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
makefile:4: recipe for target 'main.o' failed
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

I believe that it starts on reusing classb.o with the parameter -c.
To me -c is a magical "*use when i compile code without the main() function*" parameter.

I would be happy if you could enlighten me where i did go wrong, and wether what i'm trying to do is possible.

Regards, chocolateftw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your makefile should look more like this:

```
all: main

main: main.cpp classa.o classb.o
        g++ main.cpp classa.o classb.o -o main

classa.o: classa.h classa.cpp
        g++ -c classa.cpp -o classa.o

classb.o: classb.h classb.cpp
        g++ -c classb.cpp -o classb.o
```

You build `.o` files from `.cpp` files and then link `.o` files into the final output (also built from a `.cpp` file).

You need to list all relevant object files when linking and do not need to list them when only compiling (which is what happens when you use the `-c` flag which tells `gcc` to skip the linking step).

The key here is that `classa.o` does **not** depend on `classb.o` or `classb.cpp` (it probably does depend on `classb.h` though in which case you might want to add that to the requirements). The fully linked binary depends on both of them and they then depend on each other as needed.

That said you can dramatically simplify the above makefile by not specifying your own rules and simply using the built-in rules. The following makefile should do what you want.

```
all: main

main: classa.o classb.o

classa.o: classa.h
classb.o: classb.h
```

If you need custom compiler/linker flags later you can use the default variables to have them used on the appropriat lines. See [10.3 Variables Used by Implicit Rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Implicit-Variables) and [10.2 Catalogue of Built-In Rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Catalogue-of-Rules) for the variables and what rules use them.

Comment: Thank you very much for clarifying my misconception! It works. :)